# qBittorrent as a remote

Tags: remote, headless, client-server, qbittorrent

I have installed headless qBittorrent on my server. I can access it through the web UI (localy or through internet) but it's not convegnent (e.g., when I download a torrent, it's not associated with the web UI, so it does not open there, the web UI is great but far from perfect).

I wonder if it's possible to use the local qBittorrent client as a remote for the server one. In other words, could it just send the actions I do localy as actions on the server and show on the UI the state of the torrents on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was going through similar problem recently and after digging I've found that unfortunately it is not possible. qBittorrent simply does not support it.

I know this is not the answer you expect but there are other clients which have such feature, for example:

- Deluge (https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/ThinClient)
- Transmission (https://github.com/transmission-remote-gui/transgui#easy-way-recommended)

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately it's not possible using the official client.
However you should check out [Electorrent](https://github.com/tympanix/Electorrent). It works with various torrent clients (including qBittorrent of course) and is available for Windows, Linux and MacOS.

Comment: I was going to say it's great, but when you add a torrent to it, you can't chage it's directory. There is not even a config panel for the torrent after it's been added. I'll upvote though as it's a step further.

Answer (score 1):

[Transmission Remote GUI](https://github.com/xavery/transgui) is hard to beat as far as native torrent remote control GUIs go, and gives you the same uTorrent/qBittorrent-like design. You can use it with qBittorrent with https://github.com/xavery/Reflection

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for this, what you want is at https://github.com/fedarovich/qbittorrent-cli

You can then add torrents by magnet link or torrent file through cmd.

example:
`qbt torrent add url %1 -c Movies --url http://192.168.2.13:2222` in a `.bat` file where the argument would be the magnetlink, for downloading in the category `Movies`. The ip and port (`192.168.2.13:2222`) is my example, yours may differ.

Associate this bat file with `magnet://` links in your browser, and you can download those on your remote server by just clicking those links.

With a little bit of extra work you can also download torrent files this way.

For a slightly more complex example where you can choose category:

```
@echo off

echo Downloading magnet link
echo ------------------------
echo 1. MOVIES
echo 2. SERIES
echo 3. GAMES
echo 4. APPS
echo 5. TUTORIALS
echo ------------------------
choice /C 12345 /N /M "Choose category: "
if ERRORLEVEL 1 SET category=Movies
if ERRORLEVEL 2 SET category=Series
if ERRORLEVEL 3 SET category=Games
if ERRORLEVEL 4 SET category=Apps
if ERRORLEVEL 5 SET category=Tutorials
start /B /I /MIN "" qbt torrent add url %1 -c %category% --url http://192.168.2.13:2222
exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do a *local* port forwarding as such:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 pi@hostname_of_rpi
```

You can access qbittorent's UI by entering: localhost:8080 at your browser's local host.

Tested on a headless raspberry pi.